# Fill missing values after grouping by columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data relating to Borough, Street Name and Zip Code. I am trying to fill missing values in Zip Code based on Borough and Street Name

My data looks like this:

```
    ï..BOROUGH      Street.Name Zip.Code
    2850662      BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD    10464
    2850740      BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD    10464
    2850749      BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD       NA
    2850919      BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD    10464
    3491200      BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD       NA
```

Expected output is:

```
    ï..BOROUGH      Street.Name Zip.Code
    2850662      BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD    10464
    2850740      BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD    10464
    2850749      BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD    10464
    2850919      BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD    10464
    3491200      BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD    10464
```

Comment: Please show an attempt to code this yourself.

Comment: Is there is unique mapping between `Street name` and `zip code`? Else how would you fill in...

Comment: You can do this with a join. First drop all missing, then groupBy borough and street name then use the first function to get the zip code and finally left outer join the resulting data frame to the original and drop the old zip column

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to follow this approach -

1. Get the mapping of "Street_Name" and "Zip_Code" (Filter out null Zip_Code)
2. Join the master dataframe with Zip_Code dataframe using "Street_Name" and populate "Zip Code" if it's not null in master dataframe else populate from our Zip_Code dataframe.

Try this code -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

schema = StructType([StructField('BOROUGH', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('Street_Name', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Zip_Code', IntegerType(), True)])


data = [(2850662,'BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD',10464),
        (2850740,'BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD',10464),
        (2850749,'BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD',None),
        (2850919,'BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD',10464),
        (3491200,'BRONX CITY ISLAND ROAD',None)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)

df_Zip_Code = df.filter(df.Zip_Code.isNotNull()).select('Street_Name','Zip_Code').distinct()

df.alias('a').\
    join(df_Zip_Code.alias('b'),col('a.Street_Name') == col('b.Street_Name'), 'inner').\
    selectExpr("a.BOROUGH AS BOROUGH","a.Street_Name AS Street_Name","CASE WHEN a.Zip_Code IS NULL THEN b.Zip_Code ELSE a.Zip_Code END AS Zip_Code" ).\
    show()
```